# Spring Caching. what is the cache key if there is no key as well as parameter

Tags: spring, caching, key, spring-cache

Spring caching uses `key` parameter as the cache key or the parameter passed to the function if  `key` is not present. What will be the `key` if both the key and function parameter are missing?

Consider the folllowing case where neither `key` parameter nor function parameter exists. How spring caching work in such a case?

```
@Cacheable(value="cacheTest")
public string sayHello(){
    return "hello"
}
```

Comment: You will have problems in a similar use, except that there is no problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888760/cachable-on-methods-without-input-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the current *Spring Cache Abstraction* documentation on the subject of cache keys, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key).

In a nutshell...

> "*If no params are given, return SimpleKey.EMPTY.*"

In your case, *Spring* will create an "empty" `SimpleKey` (i.e. `SimpleKey.EMPTY`) as the cache key for the result ("hello") of your `sayHello()` `@Cacheable` service method.

By way of example, see this [test case](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/springcache/SimpleCacheKeyIntegrationTests.java).